# What phrases can lead to an instant comment deletion when flagged?

Tags: support, comments, flags, comment-flags

One not-so-well-known hidden feature of Stack Exchange is that, if a comment contains certain phrases, they may be instantly removed after a single flag.

For instance, any comment beginning with `+1` can be deleted after a single "Not Constructive" flag.

**Is there a list of phrases which, when included in comments, can trigger an instant deletion when flagged?**